# excel VBA how to create a dropdown list

Tags: excel, for-loop, drop-down-menu, vba

i want to make all the rows in the second columns to be a drop down list. where the user click on the cell and select any existing name.

how to do it ?

when i run  this code it display an error:

**invalid or unqualified reference**

## code:

```
Sub test()
Dim i As Integer
Dim OfficerList(4) As String

OfficerList(0) = "test1"
OfficerList(1) = "test2"
OfficerList(2) = "test3"
OfficerList(3) = "test4"
OfficerList(4) = "test5"

For i = Range("B5000").End(xlUp).Row To 2
  Select Case VBA.CDate(Cells(i, 2))
    .Delete
    .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
         Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:=Join(OfficerList, ",")
  End Select
Next


For i = Range("C5000").End(xlUp).Row To 2 Step -1 'Range upto 5000, chnge this as per your requirment'

    Select Case VBA.CDate(Cells(i, 3))

    Case Is < VBA.Date()
        Cells(i, 3).Interior.Color = vbGreen

    Case Is = VBA.Date()
        Cells(i, 3).Interior.Color = vbYellow

    Case Is > VBA.Date()
        Cells(i, 3).Interior.Color = vbRed

   End Select
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Which line does it show the error on?

Comment: it does display the line number  just compile error with the typed error above

Comment: And if you then press `Debug` on the message that pops up it will highlight the line that has the error on it

Comment: i think it stop at line **.Delete**

Comment: Youre missing a With block. It has no idea what it's doing that delete on

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't seem like the right place for `Select Case`: try this instead for your first loop

```
For i = Range("B5000").End(xlUp).Row To 2 Step -1
    With Cells(i, 2).Validation
    .Delete
    .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:=Join(OfficerList, ",")
    End With
Next i
```

Instead of `Select Case`, I just used `With` and made sure to specify that you were changing the cell's validation entry, and I changed the loop to include `Step -1` (like your second loop).

Comment: i tried your answer it did not make all the cells in the second column to be a dropdown list.....just the second row display the dropdown list

Comment: Can we get a look at your worksheet? That might help with that part.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this. I've combined your loop as well. Not sure why you're running it backwards but I've left it doing so

```
Sub test()
    Dim i As Long
    Dim OfficerList(4) As String

    OfficerList(0) = "test1"
    OfficerList(1) = "test2"
    OfficerList(2) = "test3"
    OfficerList(3) = "test4"
    OfficerList(4) = "test5"
    ' Update this with your sheet
    With Sheet1
        For i = .Range("B5000").End(xlUp).Row To 2 Step -1
          With .Cells(i, 2).Validation
            .Delete
            .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
                 Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:=Join(OfficerList, ",")
          End With

          Select Case VBA.CDate(.Cells(i, 3))
            Case Is < VBA.Date()
                .Cells(i, 3).Interior.Color = vbGreen
            Case Is = VBA.Date()
                .Cells(i, 3).Interior.Color = vbYellow
            Case Is > VBA.Date()
                .Cells(i, 3).Interior.Color = vbRed
           End Select
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```